# Alter Sender email address - WebDav

Tags: c#, email, exchange-server, exchange-server-2003

I have written an application to send an email using the WebDav protocol as shown in the following [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms878112%28v=exchg.65%29.aspx). This works perfectly, however there seems to be a limitation that the `FROM` email address must correspond with the actual exchange user account that the email is sent from.

What I want to know is whether it is possible to set the `FROM` address to be a miscellaneous email address of my choice, rather than the email address linked to my exchange account like you can do with the SMPT protocol.

Comment: WebDav is (in this case) is an abstraction so you'll have to live with the abstraction it provides. Why are you using WebDav anyway?

Comment: Limitation on the permissions opened up by the network that I need to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WebDav, you can set the FROM address with any address of users whose "Send On behalf" permission is granted to the email address linked to your exchange account.

i.e If you want to send an email from your exchange account "assistant" on behalf of user "manager", you must first grant "Send On behalf" permission of "manager" account to "assistant" account. To do that, please refer to http://www.msexchange.org/tutorials/Sending-As.html. After that, you can set the FROM address with the address of "manager" account and send email from "assistant" exchange account.

```
 strText = "From: " & <address of manager> & vbNewLine & _
            "To: " & strTo & vbNewLine & _
```

Comment: Brilliant thats just what I needed. Thanks.